# Excel vba to set picture alignment in outlook

Tags: excel, vba

With the help of below coding, I am able to paste the picture from excel to outlook. I just wanted to know if we can set the picture alignment to center. Now it is left alignment

```
With outMail  
    .To = email  
    .Subject = "OK"  
    .Display  
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
    Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
    wordDoc.Range.Paste
    .Save
    .Close 1
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
With outMail  
   .To = email  
   .Subject = "OK"  
   .Display  
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
    Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
    wordDoc.Range.Paste
    wordDoc.Application.Selection.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
   .Save
   .Close 1
End With
```

Comment: I am not saving image. Just coping from excel and pasting on outlook. so cannot attach the picture from any folder

Comment: This coding is working for me.....wordDoc.Application.Selection.Paragraphs.Alignment = 1

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll edit the answer so that others can see.

Comment: Thanks for all your help